Python projects with pick-and-choose submodules
I am building a database management project. I want it to be able to work with MariaDB and SQLServer, but I don't want the MariaDB users to have to install SQLServer drivers and libraries, or vice-versa. I've seen this done with, for instance, SQLAlchemy, but their approach doesn't look very straightforward.
What techniques are common for this kind of project structure? Is there a "best practice" for doing this?

May we ask why you want to use to 2 different database providers in the same project?  Typically, you would use only a single vendor.

@TimBiegeleisen, It's a DDL management utility.
